# How to detect if any button is pressed while we are running an endless loop in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have four buttons on GUI with different functions. I built them like:

```
button1 = TKinter.Button(btnFrame, text = "bt1", command = bt1func)
```

I also have a function `sensor()` which has to be run all the time at first, if any button is pressed, I hope we can break the loop of calling the `sensor()` and process the button's function. How could we implement it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I referred this post: [tkinter root.mainloop with While True loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop)

We can use root.after() to solve this kind of problem, for example:

```
def sensor():
    root.after(200, sensor)

root.after(200, sensor)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: An example rather than just a link would improve the quality of your answer.