# Button isn't displaying the timer

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I'm making a little game for my 4-year-old nephew. you plug two mice into the computer and try to press your button and I need the start button to turn into a timer. The problem is the button isn't displaying the time. It stops responding until the time is up and then displays "1". (keep in mind this is unfinished)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import time
score = 0
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

def button1():
    score = score - 1

def button2():
    score = score + 1

def Start():
    t = 30
    while t > 0: 
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        start.config(text=t)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)  
        t -= 1 

            

start = ttk.Button( window, text = "Start", command = Start)
start.pack(padx= 2, pady = 1)


one = ttk.Button( window, text = "Player 1", command = button1)
one.pack(padx= 2, pady = 1)



two = ttk.Button( window, text = "Player 2", command = button2)
two.pack(padx= 2, pady = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: remove `time.sleep` and replace it with `window.after(1000, Start)`. Also, replace the while loop and with `if` statement (`if t>0`) and make `t` ,  `score` global variables.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop) is an answer on the while loops indegestibility with the tkinter mainloop.

You could also solve this by running your start() function in its own thread:

```
import threading

def start():
    t = 30
    while t > 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        start_button.config(text=t)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1


def start_in_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=start)
    thread.daemon = True # forces thread to close when the tkinter mainloop is closed
    thread.start()


start_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Start", command=start_in_thread)
```

Another issue is that you buttonX() functions change the global variable `score` without gloal keyword:

```
def button1():
    global score
    score = score - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `while` and replace it with a call to `after`. I also cleaned up your script a little, and solved a future problem you were going to have. Using `threading` like the other answer states is overkill. You just need to stop blocking the `mainloop` with the `while`.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

_PLAYTIME = 10

t, score = _PLAYTIME, 0

def tally(i):
    global score
    score += i

start = tk.Button(window, text="Start")
start.pack(padx= 2, pady = 1)

tk.Button(window, text="Player 1", command=lambda: tally(1)).pack(padx=2, pady=1)
tk.Button(window, text="Player 2", command=lambda: tally(-1)).pack(padx=2, pady=1)

def game():
    global t, score
    if t > 0: 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(t, 60))
        start.config(text=f'Time: {timer} | Score: {score}')
        t -= 1
        start.after(1000, game)
    else:
        start.config(text=f'Score: {score} | Start')
        t, score = _PLAYTIME, 0
        
start.configure(command=game)

window.mainloop()
```

Here's the exact same game, but made giant and colorful as I assume 4 year olds like things... ;). I also added a 3-2-1-Go! countdown after start is pressed so, the person pressing start doesn't lose an advantage. The red and green rects are your click area. Red subtracts and green adds.

I'm not sure if you are prepared for this but, plugging 2 mice into the same computer is not going to give you 2 pointers. Maybe that's part of your game ~ fighting a 4 year old for mouse control :D. If it isn't, you are going to need TeamPlayer or something similar. Or you could simply `bind` keyboard keys instead of the mouse.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x640")
root.title('CLICKFIGHT')

#seconds to play and player handicaps 
_PLAYTIME  = 10
_HANDICAP1 = 0
_HANDICAP2 = 0

#time, score, countdown
t, s, cd = _PLAYTIME, 0, 3

#gameboard
board = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0, width=800, height=640)
board.pack()

#score adjuster
def tally(i):
    global s
    s += i

#gameboard elements    
player1 = board.create_rectangle(0, 0, 400, 600, fill="#ff0000")
player2 = board.create_rectangle(400, 0, 800, 600, fill="#00ff00")
timer   = board.create_text(200, 50, font='Helvetica 40 bold', fill='#ffffff')
score   = board.create_text(600, 50, font='Helvetica 40 bold', fill='#ffffff')
button  = board.create_rectangle(0, 600, 800, 640, fill="#0000ff", tag="button")
start   = board.create_text(400, 620, font='Helvetica 20 bold', fill='#ffffff', text="START", tag="button")
cdown   = board.create_text(400, 300, font='Helvetica 80 bold', fill='#ffffff')

#game countdown
def countdown():
    global cd, p
    #so you can't click start again
    board.tag_unbind("button", '<1>')
    if cd > 0:
        board.itemconfig(cdown, text=cd)
        cd-=1
        root.after(800, countdown)
    else:
        board.itemconfig(cdown, text='GO!')
        root.after(200, game)
        cd = 3

#actual game
def game():
    global t, s
    #game stats
    board.itemconfig(timer, text='Time:\t{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(t, 60)))
    board.itemconfig(score, text=f'Score:\t{s}')
    board.itemconfig(start, text='PLAYING...')
    if t > 0: 
        #game looping
        t -= 1
        root.after(1000, game)
        board.itemconfig(cdown, text='')
    else:
        #reset everything
        t, s = _PLAYTIME, 0
        board.itemconfig(start, text='START')
        board.itemconfig(cdown, text='GAME OVER')
        board.tag_bind("button", '<1>', lambda e: countdown())

#mouse events
board.tag_bind(player1 , '<1>', lambda e: tally(-(1+_HANDICAP1)))
board.tag_bind(player2 , '<1>', lambda e: tally(1+_HANDICAP2))
board.tag_bind("button", '<1>', lambda e: countdown())

root.mainloop()
```