# Using tkinter how do you have a set of coordinates always updating?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to constantly draw a set of objects on the screen whose coordinates are determined by a changing list of numbers. I am using a JSON file to read coordinates. The JSON file will look like this for example:

```
{"coords_1": ["0", "0", "150", "120", "130", "180", "210", "160", "150", "30", "100", "20"],
"coords_2": ["450", "0", "250", "120", "240", "180", "210", "200", "150", "150", "100", "20"]}
```

And my Python code looks like this for now

```
import json
from tkinter import *

def read(number):
    with open("coords.json", "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    json_object = json.loads(data)
    s = "coords_"
    s += str(number)
    return json_object[s]


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

canvas = Canvas(root, height = 500, width = 500)

#ALWAYS UPDATE THIS
object_1 = canvas.create_polygon(read(1), outline="blue", fill="orange", width=2)
object_2 = canvas.create_polygon(read(2), outline="blue", fill="green", width=2)

canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

This works fine, however, I want to be able to change the data in the JSON file thus changing the position of the object but I am unable to. Does anyone know how this would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to this post [tkinter root.mainloop with While True loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop)

```
def repeat():
    object_1 = canvas.create_polygon(read(2), outline="blue", fill="orange", width=2)
    root.after(1000, repeat)

root.after(1000, repeat)
```

Comment: But you are creating *new* polygon every second.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, didn't write it in the code but I use ```canvas.delete``` aswell

Comment: You don't need to delete and recreate, just create once and update the coords.