# Trying to run a while true loop alongside tkinter mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying to code a game of life with 4 process each dealing with a quarter of the cells.
Here's my issue:
I use tkinter's canvas to display the cells and I have to run a while true loop which updates the cells alongside it but I don't know how to do so.

Here's my full code below:
The display function is where I need to run both the tkinter mainloop and the canvas_fill function which has the while true loop.

The other functions are as follow:

- seed generates the first alive cells
- mini_grid which manages each subgrid

```
from tkinter import * 
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

#matrix size
size = 20
#seed
x_table = [7,7,8,8,8,9]
y_table = [4,5,4,5,6,6]

def display(Cells,window,PipeA):
    #i,j,alive

    canvas = Canvas(window,height='400',width='400')
    canvas.pack()
    
    window.mainloop()
    canvas_fill(Cells,window,PipeA,canvas)
    

def canvas_fill(Cells, window, PipeA, canvas):
    while True:
        print("looping")
        [i,j,alive]=PipeA.recv()
        x= (i*20)-20
        y= (j*20)-20
        if alive == 0:
            Cells[((i*size)+j)%(size**2)]=0
            canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+20,y+20,fill='white')
        else:
            Cells[((i*size)+j)%(size**2)]=1
            print("case vivante crée")
            canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+20,y+20,fill='lime green')

def seed(Cells,lock,PipeB):
    for i in range(len(x_table)):
        with lock:
            fill_cell(x_table[i],y_table[i],1,Cells,lock)
            #envoyer par pipe
            PipeB.send((x_table[i],y_table[i],1))


def mini_grid(id,Cells,lock,PipeB):
    near = [-1,-9,-10,-11,+1,+9,+10,+11]
    z=0
    while z<10:
        z+=1
        for i in range(int(size*size/4)):
            n=i//size #ligne n
            p=i%size # colonne p
            if id==1:
                p=p+size
            if id==2:
                n=n+size
            if id==3:
                n=n+size
                p=p+size
            cells_alive_around = 0
            for j in near:
                if Cells[((n*size)+p+j)%(size*size)]==1:
                    cells_alive_around +=1
            if Cells[((n*size)+p)%(size**2)] == 0:
                #cellule morte
                if cells_alive_around == 3:
                    #devient vivante
                    PipeB.send((n,p,1))
                    Cells[(n*size+p)%(size**2)]=1
            else:
                #cellule vivante
                if cells_alive_around <2 or cells_alive_around >3:
                    #devient morte
                    PipeB.send((n,p,0))
                    print(n*size+p)
                    print('n ',n)
                    Cells[(n*size+p)%(size**2)]=0
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    size = 10*10 # grille 20*20 donc 4 sous-grilles 10*10
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Game of life")

    lock = mp.Lock()
    Cells = mp.Array('i',[0]*size**2)
    Grids = [0,0,0,0]

    PipeA,PipeB = mp.Pipe()
    Display = mp.Process(target = display,args=(Cells,window,PipeA))
    Display.start()
    seed(Cells,lock,PipeB)
    for i in range(4): #Création des 4 sous grilles
        Grids[i] = mp.Process(target= mini_grid,args=(i,Cells,lock,PipeB))
        Grids[i].start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to set the canvas_fill() function to run on a cadence. Try implementing the solution found here. [tkinter root.mainloop with While True loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131612/9257989)

I'm no expert here, but I hope this at least gets you going down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found out that I can just use
window.update() inside of my while loop instead of the mainloop()