# Tkinter window not responding when push buttton

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that I wrote in tkinter, but if the while true loop starts running, the window stops working(not responding) what should I do?

code:

````
import pyautogui
import sys
import keyboard

def basla():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("shift"):
            pyautogui.press("enter")
            pyautogui.typewrite("/pull ")

        elif keyboard.is_pressed("E"):
            pyautogui.press("enter")
            pyautogui.typewrite("/me WHO GAS")
            pyautogui.press("enter")


def bitir():
    sys.exit()

pencere = Tk()
pencere.title("Keybinder")
pencere.geometry("300x300+10+10");
baslat_buton = Button(pencere)
baslat_buton.config(text="Başlat", bg="black",width=8,height=2, fg="white", command=basla)
baslat_buton.place(x=100,y=100)


bitir_buton = Button(pencere)
bitir_buton.config(text="Bitir", bg="black", fg="white",width=8,height=2, command=bitir)
bitir_buton.place(x=100,y=150)
mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

"In tkinter don't use while True which runs forever (or runs longer time) because it blocks mainloop() in tkinter and it can't update items in window, and it looks like it freezes."

Check out this topic and see if it makes it clear to you. [tkinter root.mainloop with While True loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131486/tkinter-root-mainloop-with-while-true-loop)